# Android Gradle flavors get buildConfigField in java

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have to flavors for ads and no ads for my app. I created a buildConfigField("String", "ADS_ENABLED", "TRUE") and buildConfigField("String", "ADS_ENABLED", "FALSE") and would like to know how do I access this in java to show or not show ads?

This is my flavors:

```
flavorDimensions 'ads'
    productFlavors {
        ads {
            dimension 'ads'
            buildConfigField("String", "ADS_ENABLED", "TRUE")
        }
        noAds {
            dimension 'ads'
            buildConfigField("String", "ADS_ENABLED", "FALSE")
        }
    }
```

I tried BuildConfig.ADS_ENABLED but the only options I got are:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this value with:

```
BuildConfig.ADS_ENABLED
```

It is a `String`.